# non-typical left menu in iOS (screens attached)

Tags: ios, iphone, mmdrawercontroller, jasidepanels, viewdeck

I need to implement non-typical left menu. For instance, main screen looks like this:

[image]

When we press left menu button (at the top-left part of the screen) we should see this:

[image]

I tried a lot of solutions ([ZUUIRevealController](https://github.com/alecgorge/ZUUIRevealController), [ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck), [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) (there you can scale left menu, but not center), [JASidePanels](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels)), but they didn't help.

Is it any way to implement scaling of the central view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ECLidingViewController with Zoom animation,
https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController
it looks like this:

[image: ECSlindingViewController]